# ASP Net MVC Передача массива, либо 2х мерного массива bool`ов

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, razor, asp

Пишу сайт для прохождения тестов. 
Вопрос такой: 
Делаю страницу с ответом на вопросы и необходимо передать ответ в контроллер для обработки (отвечает пользователь выбором чекбоксов). На странице может быть, сколь угодно вопросов, в вопросе может быть сколь угодно ответов. 
Так вот:

```
Код представления
<div class="">
            @{int j = 0,k = 0;
            foreach (var item in Model.Questions)
                {int i = 0;j++;
                    <div class=d-flex align-self-stretch ftco-animate">
                        <div class="media block-6 services d-flex align-items-start">
                            <div class="media-body pl-4">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <h3 class="heading">@j ) @item.Name</h3>
                                    <input name="id" value="@j" style="display:none" />
                                </div>
                                @foreach (var answer in item.Answers)
                                {i++;k++;
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <input value="true" type="checkbox" name="ans" />
                                        <p class="mb-0">@i</p><p> ) @answer.Text</p>
                                        <input value="@i" style="display:none" />
                                    </div>
                                }
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                }
            }
        </div>

код контроллера
public ActionResult AnswerTest(string name, string option, bool[] ans)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

С таким кодом Я получаю массив только выбранных чекбоксов, а хотелось бы получить массив всех чекбоксов, либо массив, где номер ячейки соответствует номеру вопроса.

P.S.: В идеале получить двумерный массив который содержит номер вопроса и номера ответов. 
Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

В общем пока решилось передачей массива номеров вопросов:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="@answer.id" name="idA" />
```